# Clip-path using inline SVG clipping wrong elements when position:absolute

Tags: css, html, svg

This is a little hard to explain, so here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4wSh/) to show what I mean.

```
<style>
    .clip {
        clip-path: url(#clippath);
        -o-clip-path: url(#clippath);
        -moz-clip-path: url(#clippath);
        -webkit-clip-path: url(#clippath);
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <clippath id="clippath">
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="320" />
            </clippath>
        </defs>
    </svg>

    <div id="d1">Bottom</div>
    <div id="d2" class="clip">Middle</div>
    <div id="d3">Top</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I want to apply a clip-path to an absolutely positioned element, however I am finding that all other absolutely positioned elements which appear after it in the DOM will be clipped too. This isn't the case with relatively positioned elements, oddly.

How can I make sure that only the desired element is clipped? I can't see anything wrong with my code. Is this a bug?

Comment: Seems to work fine on Firefox. Report a bug against whatever UA you are using I guess.

Comment: I have just tried, and yes it does. Firefox seems to be the only browser this works in though. Is there an alternative to clip-path which has better support?

Comment: are you applying SVG clip to HTML content?? I don't think that is possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now behaves correctly in all browsers I've tested aside from Internet Explorer (which lacks support for clippath on HTML elements entirely), and as such it's no longer a problem.